# join with a static value for a column in zf2

Tags: php, join, zend-framework2

I'm writing a PHP application using zend framework 2.2.2.
I'm trying to create a select query with a join that contains a static value condition.

this is my code:

```
    $this->select->join('global_image_link','global_image_link.table_pkey=drink_flavor.drink_flavor_id AND global_image_link.global_image_type_id=2',array())
```

now the end of the query contains the following:

```
global_image_link.global_image_type_id=2
```

when i do getSqlStringForSqlObject to return the query the end of the query is

```
 AND `global_image_link`.`global_image_type_id`=`2`
```

because it adds `` to the number it searches for column called 2 instead of the number 2.

I guess i need to escape that number somehow or wrap it with some class.

any ideas how to resolve the issue?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use new Zend_Db_Expr like that:

```
$this->select->join('global_image_link',new Zend_Db_Expr('global_image_link.table_pkey=drink_flavor.drink_flavor_id AND global_image_link.global_image_type_id=2'),array())
```

Zend_Db_Expr does not escape values, so be careful when using it.

Comment: i need to use new Expression instead of Zend_Db_Expr, using zf2 2.2.2 probably Zend_Db_Expr is in older ver or zf1. anyhow.. that resolved my issue. thanks

Comment: @ufk. use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression in ZF2